# Logic/Algorithm for sorting Bus route options

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement below bus route sorting algorithm.

Customer searches for buses from A to B and selects preferred carrier. (Ex: Dallas to Chicago on Greyhound)
Assuming there is a web service that returns List of bus route options from A to B. Each BusOption object has list of segments with Carrier as one of attributes, along with departure time, arrival time etc

I need to sort the results in the below order.

1. First Show direct buses from A to B on preferred carrier. (within each group sort by earliest arrival time)
2. Connecting buses from A to B on preferred carrier.
3. Buses on preferred carrier from station A connecting to non-preferred carrier from intermediate stations.
4. Direct buses on non preferred carriers
5. Connecting non preferred from A and then preferred  carrier from intermediate stations.
6. Connecting non preferred carriers through out the route

Example Ex: Dallas to Chicago on Greyhound

```
ORG         DEST        CARRIER     DEPART  ARRIVAL
```

1. Dallas      Chicago      Greyhound      6 AM  11 PM

2. Dallas      Chicago      Greyhound      7 AM  11.45 PM
3. Dallas - Kansas          Greyhound       6 AM  1 PM

   Kansas city  - Chicago  Greyhound       2 PM 10PM
4. Dallas - Kansas          Greyhound       6 AM  1 PM

   Kansas city  - Chicago  MEGABUS         2 PM 10PM
5. Dallas      Chicago      Megabus      6 AM  11 PM
6. Dallas - Kansas          Megabus     6 AM  1 PM

   Kansas city  - Chicago  Greyhound           2 PM 10PM
7. Dallas - Kansas          MEGABUS     6 AM  1 PM

   Kansas city  - Chicago  MEGABUS         2 PM 10PM
   My thoughts:

I initially thought of using a Set for each group, thus six set objects.
while mapping WS response to my custom response of BusOption class containing list of Segments and isPreferredCarrier flag, 
I thought to set prefferredCarrier flag to false if atleast one carrier is non prefferred. 
Then,

```
If(routeOption.getSegments.size()==1 and routeOption.isPreferredCarrier()){
    Add to Set 1
}else //continue similar logic and add to corresponding Set
```

Merge all sets in the required order of 1 to 6.

Is this the right and optimum approach ? Please advise if you think of a better logic for sorting

Comment: What are you trying to ask exactly? I don't see an explicit question here, which will deter a lot of people from answering.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set isPreferredCarrier flag to false if atleast one carrier is non preferred, because in this case you cannot set 3. So, you should keep the flag for each segment:

```
if (routeOption.getSegments.size()==1 &&
    routeOption.getSegments[0].isPreferredCarrier())
    Add to Set 1;
else if (routeOption.getSegments.size()==2 &&
    routeOption.getSegments[0].isPreferredCarrier() &&
    routeOption.getSegments[1].isPreferredCarrier())
    Add to Set 2;
else if (routeOption.getSegments.size()==2 &&
    routeOption.getSegments[0].isPreferredCarrier())
    Add to set 3;
else ...
```